# Online - Share list data between two sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, lookup-column

I'm using SharePoint Online and I have two subsites.

One is called `Customers` and the second site is called `Pvt Documents`.

I've a document library in `Pvt Documents` where I would like to "link" a document to a specific customer that is currently in the `Customer List` on the `Customer` site.

I have thought using a lookup field but this field can only search in the same site.

If is not possible to search in a list from another site, is it possible to duplicate the `customer list` on the `Pvt Documents` and keep it updated? Or a better question: which is the right way to do this?

Comment: both the sites are in the same site collection?

Comment: @AakashMorya yes they are in the same site collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both the subsites are in the same site/site collection then,

Just create a site column with `lookup` type and configure with the required list column.

Go in the document library setting and select `Add from existing site column` and you will find your created lookup column there.

Just add it.

For more and detail information read [Create a SharePoint Lookup Column to another Site](https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/create-a-sharepoint-lookup-column-to-another-site/)

Exact quote from the link

> "As long as you stay in the same Site Collection, you can create a
>   lookup Site Column that will be used to get information from a list
>   that is available in a parent site. The Site Column must be created in
>   the same site as the referenced list/library."

If your both the sites are in the same site collection, then in that case refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/157584/30145) answer.

Comment: Should the "Customer" site has to be the root site?

Comment: Yes, the site on which you are creating the site column must be a parent site.. I just verified. Let me dig more into it..